# XML deleting a node by attribute value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, html, removechild, xmlnode

I want to delete a node with a particular name attribute specified by a user. What am I doing wrong? Let's sat user enters: "cat" and whenever system finds an animal with an attribute cat it deletes it. Animal nodes have no children.

This is a simplification of the .xml file

```
<animals>
    <animal name="elephant"></animal>
    <animal name="cat"></animal>
    ...    
</animals>
```

This is my code for deleting a particular node from xml file.

```js
function delete() {
    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("file.xml");
    root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("animal");

    for (i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
        if (root[i].nodeType == 1) {
            if (root[i].attributes[0].value == document.getElementById("del").value) {
                xmlDoc.removeChild(root[i]);
                display(); // function displaying the results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The local variables in your function should be declared with `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<animal>` nodes are not children of the top-level node in the XML DOM, so `xmlDoc.removeChild()` won't work.

```
root[i].parentNode.removeChild(root[i]);
```

That said, you'll probably run into difficulties due to the fact that the node list returned from `getElementsByTagName()` is **live**. As you remove elements, the list will shrink and you'll wind up skipping some. You can change the loop to deal with that:

```
for (var i=0; i<root.length; ) {
    if(root[i].nodeType==1 && root[i].attributes[0].value==document.getElementById("del").value) {
        xmlDoc.removeChild(root[i]);
        display(); // function displaying the results
    }
    else
        i++;
}
```